# PHP mySQL - Multiple games/events on same day display

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a sports website and ran into an issue.  There is more than one game on different days and I'm only wanting the date to display once instead of once for every game to be played on that date.

For example: http://seohiosports.com/mastergirlsbasketballschedule2014.php
You will see immediately that there are two games listed on November 26.  They are displayed like this:

> November 26, 2013 
>   Tri-Valley at Crooksville
>   November 26, 2013 
>   Sheridan at John Glenn

I want it to be displayed like this:

> November 26, 2013
>   Tri-Valley at Crooksville
>   Sheridan at John Glenn

Here is the code I'm working with, for some reason or another, I'm struggling to come up with the test/loop I need to make this work how I want it to.

```
if($num > 0)
{   
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {           
        echo '<b>'. date("F d, Y",strtotime($row['date'])) .' </b><br/>
              '. $row['awayteam'] . ' '. $row['awayscore'] .' at '. $row['hometeam'] . ' '. $row['homescore'] .' <br/><br/>';
    }

    mysql_free_result($r);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.  I think the answer is probably simple, but I'm struggling for one reason or another.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<? if ($num > 0)
{   
    $temp_date = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {   
        if ($temp_date != $row['date']) {
            $temp_date = $row['date'];
            echo '<b>'. date("F d, Y",strtotime($row['date'])) .' </b><br/>';
        }

           echo $row['awayteam'] . ' '. $row['awayscore'] .' at '. $row['hometeam'] . ' '. $row['homescore'] .' <br/><br/>';
    }

    mysql_free_result($r);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is looking good.

Only problem is that I'm getting two <br/> tags in after each game.  I would like to only have one after games on the same day.  I'm going to see if I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I could just add a div tag for each row and use CSS to add spacing?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out by adding a <br/> tag before the echo date was executed!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($num > 0){
  $dates = Array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
    if(!in_array($row['date'], $dates)){
      $dates[] = $row['date'];
      echo $row['date'] . '</br>';
    }

     echo $row['awayteam'] . ' '. $row['awayscore'] .' at '. $row['hometeam'] . ' '. $row['homescore'] .' <br/><br/>';
  }
  mysql_free_result($r);
}
```